# %LIKE% retrieves eg. WOMEN DATA when calling MEN

Tags: php, regex, laravel

```
  $itemList = DB::table('items')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->where('item_status', 2)
                ->where(function($query) use($queryArr)
                {
                    foreach($queryArr as $uID){
                        $query->whereRaw("tags LIKE '%$uID%'");
                    }
                })->paginate(21);
```

I have been facing this issue since a long time. Problem when you do a LIKE search is it grabs the data of **WOMEN** when it's just eg **MEN**

Mainly because MEN is inside Women

I also tried the following but failed(This sort of grab a word) `men` without `women` data

```
$query->where('tags', 'LIKE', '%'.$uID.'%');
SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';
```

How do i use that Word boundary query in laravel query builder

Tried this and still failed $query->whereRaw("tags LIKE REGEXP '[[:<:]]Men[[:>:]]'");

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP '[[:<:]]Men[[:>:]]')' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from items where item_status = ? and (tags LIKE REGEXP '[[:<:]]Men[[:>:]]')) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 2, ))
```

I also understand some asked why not just created a proper way of handling these item's category. Well i think for now using Full Text Search is fine for me at most when it come to scaling i will use elastic search. true?

**UPDATE**

Apologies for not giving an example of tags

Bag,Shoes,**Men**,Wedges

Bag,Shoes,**Men**

**Men**,Shoes,Bag

Comment: Can you show us an example of the value of `tags`?

Comment: because when you use %men% that means women will return true. Also nomen will return true.. anything ends with men will return true..

Comment: Do you have a space separated list of tags in field `tags`?

Comment: @AlexeyMatskoff Commas, just updated.

Comment: @lukasgeiter just updated.

Comment: @geekido yeah that's the issue i'm trying to tackle

Comment: then use WHERE tags = '.$uID.' for certain thing.

Comment: @geekido but straight after the word, i have a comma, does it still work that way?

Comment: one reason why you shouldn't use comma seperated list. it is messy.

Comment: This would moment for you to think about recreating your tables and use `FOREIGN KEY` (if your db is like "`innoDB`") -- is just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If values are separated by commas, try to use following

```
WHERE `tags` REGEXP "(^|,)men(,|$)"
```

This will require to have comma or end of string around the word men.

Comment: For the First and last tag , it would space at the front and last tag, space at the end. It would still work?

Comment: I had following values: "men", "women", "women,men", "men,women", "dogs,men,birds". I ran following query: SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `tags` REGEXP "(^|,)men(,|$)" and it returned me all records except "women". As it should be. Checked on MySQL. You can give more examples and I can check the query on them.

Comment: What about Men,Shoes,Bag < His example

Comment: @FlyingAtom, it is selected

Comment: @AlexeyMatskoff but you said "This will require to have comma or end of string around the word men."

Comment: I've also tested my query on all the examples above + copy of them with "Men" replaced with "Women". It worked good.

Comment: @FlyingAtom maybe my words are not enough clear =) Sorry if so.

Comment: @FlyingAtom He meant that with this regex it will only match `men` if there's a comma or nothing at the beginning/end of the word. Which is exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @AlexeyMatskoff so if my tags is like Men,Shoes,Shirt your Regex can grab it too? because before men doesnt have a comma but yours seems to require it. I tried Home,Decoration,Men , it doesnt detect men

Comment: @CodeGuru, yes, it should grab such values as well.
Here are my [examples](http://i.gyazo.com/de1552182a4141a50b4f7cca10ff8437.png)

And here are the [results of the query](http://i.gyazo.com/b45492d8333e76be5519163eac114f38.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your REGEXP solution is throwing the syntax error because of the extra LIKE keyword. The correct syntax is simply `WHERE column REGEXP 'pattern'`.

If you find this hard to remember, try using RLIKE instead, which is a synonym for MySQL's REGEXP. There is less chance you will accidentally write `WHERE column LIKE RLIKE ...` in your query because it is more obviously redundant.

The pattern itself should work fine. Personally, I dislike using those word boundary classes in MySQL; since you know your tags are comma delimited and space padded, `[ ,]Man[ ,]` would function just as well. The word boundary class breaks at punctuation other than underscores, so you could run into trouble if you have tags that are hyphenated, for instance.

If you want to use multiple word tags with spaces, either of the previous patterns is buggy. In that case I would try to stick with commas as your delimiter, get rid of the whitespace padding and use anchors instead, as suggested in one of the other answers: `(^|,)Man($|,)`

Answer (score -1):

In your query you said : Find anything that contains the tag `'MEN' => '%MEN%'`, that's why it shows: WOMEN AND MEN, so to answer to your question you should use starts with instead of contains, like this :

```
$query->where('tags', 'LIKE', $uID.'%');
```

Comment: Apologies for not giving an example of tags Women,Shoes,Men,Wedge(Doesnt make sense) but yea

Comment: See it wont grab because before the word men, it doesnt have wild card. But before it, it's a comma

Comment: ->where(function($query) use($queryArr)
                {
                    foreach($queryArr as $uID){
                        $query->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', $uID .'%');
                    }

Comment: Lol you dont understand at all, Why answer when you dont understand? You say %fake% what the hell, if it's %men% it would call women's data which is what he is trying to SOLVE. LOL You are giving HIS PROBLEM as solution? What?